# unable to resolve dependency tree when installing @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I created a new project `react-native init MyProject` and after opening it in VSCode the first thing I did was to install the navigation.

`npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack`

It throws the error, then I did it separately meaning first I did `npm install @react-navigation/native` it gets installed successfully then after this I did `npm install @react-navigation/stack` then the error came again:

```
 npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
 tree npm ERR!  npm ERR! While resolving: MyProject@0.0.1 npm ERR!
 Found: react@17.0.1 npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!  
 react@"17.0.1" from the root project npm ERR!   peer react@"*" from
 @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3 npm ERR!  
 node_modules/@react-navigation/stack npm ERR!    
 @react-navigation/stack@"^5.14.2" from the root project npm ERR!  npm
 ERR! Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.0" from
 @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10 npm ERR!
 node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view npm ERR!  
 @react-native-community/masked-view@"^0.1.10" from the root project
 npm ERR!   peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">= 0.1.0" from  
 @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3 npm ERR!  
 node_modules/@react-navigation/stack npm ERR!    
 @react-navigation/stack@"^5.14.2" from the root project npm ERR!  npm
 ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this
 command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an
 incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! 
 npm ERR! See /Users/chaudhrytalha/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full
 report.
 
 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!    
 /Users/chaudhrytalha/.npm/_logs/2021-03-17T10_09_02_128Z-debug.log
```

I even tried installing `npm install @react-native-community/masked-view` but get similar errors.

Comment: Have you checked all of the libs you have to install for the navigation to work? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 8):

This will solve the issue

**npm install "--legacy-peer-deps" @react-navigation/stack --force**

Comment: Just a bit of typo: "--legacy-peer-deps"

Answer (score 4):

Using **yarn** instead of **npm** is solved my issue.

Answer (score 4):

Use yarn package manager

```
 npm install --global yarn
```

use yarn to resolve your package.json deps

```
yarn install
```

Comment: but why is it happening there? why does using yarn solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Same issue and 2 suggestion [Github-9426](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9426#issuecomment-801571612)

1.option is use yarn instead of npm. worked for me.

```
yarn add @react-native-community/masked-view
yarn add @react-navigation/stack
```

2.option is react-navigation v6. but not working for me. v6 is not stable yet.

Answer (score 0):

Removing undefined line in the dependencies secton of the package.json file and then reinstalling navigation worked for me

Answer (score 0):

npm install @react-navigation/stack --force

Install it with --force at the end

Answer (score -1):

Try installing navigation in the same directory as your project

Comment: Answers are supposed to have a working or trying solution. If you have an opinion, please post it as a comment.